# In Javascript, is function declaration the only way to create a constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor

In JavaScript, is function declaration the only way to create a constructor that can be used to instantiate a new object. If so, Why ? This question arises from the following code.

```
var customevent = {
        prop1 : "div",
        prop2 : "div2"
    }

    var myevent_obj = new customevent();
```

Browser JS console show

```
SyntaxError: customevent is not a constructor.
```

Comment: `var a = Object.create(customevent);` will create a new object using `customevent` as its prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, a [*constructor*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-constructor) is an object that implements the internal [`[[call]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) and [`[[Construct]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) methods. Except for a few built–in functions, all native functions are constructors. Most host functions are not constructors, though some are.

EMCAScript 2015 also defines exotic function objects, which might be built–in but need not be constructors.

There are two methods for creating a native function that can be a constructor:

1. Function declaration: `function MyConstructor(){...}`
2. Function expression (usually through assignment): `var MyConstructor = function(){...};`

That's it.

In the OP:

```
var customevent = {
        prop1 : "div",
        prop2 : "div2"
    }
```

*customevent* is an Object, not a Function. Plain objects don't implement either `[[Call]]` or `[[Construct]]` internal methods, therefore they can't be constructors. They can be used as prototypes though:

```
function customConstructor(){}
customConstructor.prototoype = customevent;
```

or

```
var newCustomEvent = Object.create(customevent);
```